# Bootstrap Input background doesn't cover the entire input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I am trying to develop a simple form page using Bootstrap. However, I want a different *background-color* than the classic white. Because of this, I added a new background-color (light gray) by overriding the *"form-control"* class's background color.

When I added this I sometimes got a part of the right side cut off, I don't really know why. It happened when I added the color so I guess it has something with the background color to do. But why I don't know. That's why I am asking you! :)

Here is an image of the "input":

[image: Image cut off]

Here is the **affected** code:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:400,700%7CRaleway:400,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
.formKeepLeft {
    display: flex;
}

.skipLine {
    clear: left;
}

.form-control, .form-control:focus {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.skipLine {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <!--- Col 1 --->
        <form>
            <div class="formKeepLeft">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Namn</label>
                    <input type="input" class="form-control " size="100%" id="inputName" placeholder="">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                    <label for="inputPassword">E-post</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control " size="100%" id="inputEmail" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Form row 2 -->
            <div class="form-group skipLine">
                <label for="inputPassword">Ämne</label>
                <input type="input" class="form-control " size="100%" id="inputÄmne" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- JS files: jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

It often gets cut off when I resize the page, so for example, it might work for *col-lg* but when I **resize** **it** to another size this sometimes happens. I tried using *background-size* but without any luck.

I want to achieve this:

[image: How I want it to look]

The image is a bit small, but basically it is the exact same image **but without the right part cut off**. Does anyone know the solution? What did I do wrong?

Thanks, any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: I don't see any cut-off, can you mention exact breakpoint where you find this

Comment: Yeah, well in lg mode it appears on my page. I'll update the code to my entire page

Comment: Even though I add my entire code to the snippet it  doesn't connect the  css as on my page

Comment: I added all the code, still doesn't work in the snippet though

Comment: now it works, see

Comment: Yeah thanks that works, now you can clearly see the cut off part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just because of `border-radius`, you can add `border-width: 0;` to remove that gap.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:400,700%7CRaleway:400,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       
<!-- JS files: jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.formKeepLeft {
    display: flex;
}

.skipLine {
    clear: left;
}

.form-control, .form-control:focus {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-width: 0;
}

.skipLine {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <!--- Col 1 --->
        <form>
            <div class="formKeepLeft">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Namn</label>
                    <input type="input" class="form-control " size="100%" id="inputName" placeholder="">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                    <label for="inputPassword">E-post</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control " size="100%" id="inputEmail" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Form row 2 -->
            <div class="form-group skipLine">
                <label for="inputPassword">Ämne</label>
                <input type="input" class="form-control " size="100%" id="inputÄmne" placeholder="">
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that works when I don't focus it I see, but if I click the input and focus it. It cuts off the right part? I put "border-color: transparent" last in style file and affects both .form-control and -form-control:focus

Comment: take your time :)

Comment: I tried putting it in two seperate "styles" but that didnt work.

Comment: see my answer now

Comment: Thanks! that solved the issue, so it was the border that struggled.. thanks for solving it! Really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to help you brother

Answer (score 0):

Add border:0; it will show space differently sometimes other corners better to make the border as 0

```
.form-control, .form-control:focus {
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 0px;
 background-color: lightgray;
 border: 0;
}
```